# Create table from text file using PHP

Tags: php, text-files, tabular, sentence

I need to create a table with borders from the text file (this text file is updated every time when someone finishes filling a form. One row, one person):

```
Herard|TRO789|Suzuki|France|Gendolfina|Fresko|food|500|2015-04-25 14:40
Bob|MGA789|Mercedes|Latvia|Polaris|Dread|parts|1000|2015-04-26 16:15
```

I've already created a script which reads every word separately, but don't know how to to put them to table:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("info.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
while (!feof($file)){   
    $data = fgets($file); 
    list($name, $number, $type, $country, $company, $gcompany, $supply, $weight, $datetime) = explode("|", $data);
    }
    fclose($failas);
?>
```

So I need a script which could read the text file and create a table with the same number of rows as the text file has.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create an HTML table? Or insert into a database? Have you tried reading some tutorials?

Comment: Ye HTML table. I was searching net for 2 hours.

Comment: Googling HTML table tutorial brings up 10 million results.

Comment: I KNOW HOW to create table. I NEED help creating script which READ WORDS from text file and puts into TABLE

Comment: Umm you echo the variables into the table......

Comment: Why don't you post the HTML table code you already have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str_replace` to replace the `|` signs with HTML table cell delimiters.

```
<?php
echo '<table border="1">';
$file = fopen("info.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
while (!feof($file)){   
    $data = fgets($file); 
    echo "<tr><td>" . str_replace('|','</td><td>',$data) . '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: Thanx rly good idea!! :) Iam a bit tired today so OUT of ideas.

Comment: btw, where could i put <th></th>?

Comment: Between line 2 and 3: `<tr><th>Column 1</th><th>....</th></tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not clean but works.  you can also use explode to create an array instead of many variables:

```
<table>   
    <?php
        $file = fopen("info.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        while (!feof($file)){   
            $data = fgets($file); 
            list($name, $number, $type, $country, $company, $gcompany, $supply, $weight, $datetime) = explode("|", $data);
    ?> 
    <tr>
        <td><?=$name ?></td>
        <td><?=$number ?></td>
        ...
    </tr>
    <?php
        }
        fclose($failas);
   ?>
</table>
```