# Display contents of .txt file using php via a select box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using xammp to host a php page locally with a seperate folder called "files" in the root directory.

in my "files" folder I have multiple different text files that seperate content using the "," as a delimiter. ***Example: here,is,some,information,from,a,text,file***

Currently I have the following code:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="text-center form-inline">
<select name="s1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
  <?php 
       foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/files/*') as $filename){
       $filename = basename($filename);
       echo "<option value='" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
    }
?>
</select> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="submit">Display Contents</button>
</form>
```

This is populating the select box with the text files I have in the "files" directory.

The output I am looking for is that on click of the submit button, the content of whichever text file I have selected in the select box is read to the webpage, exploding the content on each ","

So if i was to select a file that contained hello,stack,over,flow

I could then display that in a 4 column table with 1 word in each colomn

**EDIT:**

```
<?php 

    $lines = file("files/random.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $data = array_map(function($v){
        list($one, $two, $three) = explode(",", $v);
        return ["table header" => $one, "table header" => $two, "table header" => $three];
    }, $lines);
?>
```

This is my current explode function which works perfectly fine when I input the static filepath but I just dont know how to link the two together so that the content displayed changes based on which file i select from the select box

Comment: what was your approach?

Comment: what error you got..?

Comment: have you tried any thing so far?

Comment: after form submit u need to read $_POST['s1'] to find out which file u want to read and for next steps read this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867025/create-table-from-text-file-using-php

Comment: I added my explode function to the question, my problem is just linking the two, I am pretty new to PHP so dont really know what I am doing, just fiddling!