# generated HTML table from a text file with PHP. End of file is displayed as a table entry. How can I prevent this?

Tags: php

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867025/create-table-from-text-file-using-php) the solution. The problem is that the script also sees the end of file as an entry and displays it as an empty line in the table.

[Print screen of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evBLi.png)

Content of the text file:

```
Select browser|select_browser.pdf|comment of the file|PDF|03.03.2022
Print document|print_document.pdf|comment of the file|PDF|01.01.2022
```

PHP script:

```
<?php
 # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29867025/create-table-from-text-file-using-php
 $file = fopen("info.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
 while (!feof($file)) {
  $data = fgets($file); 
  list($filename, $linktext, $comment, $filetype, $datetime) = explode("|", $data);
?> 

 <tr>
  <td><a href="<?=$filename ?>"><?=$linktext ?></a></td>
  <td><?=$comment ?></td>
  <td style="text-align: right;"><?=$filetype ?></td>
  <td style="text-align: right;"><?=$datetime ?></td>
 </tr>

<?php
 }
 fclose($failas);
?>
```

How can I prevent this? I thank you for your help!

Comment: Put a logic test to check whether the variables ( `$file_description`, `$name` etc ) are set and only print the table row if they are

Comment: If there's a trailing "new line" then this makes sense as it will return that last line. You can fix this issue and simplify your code by moving `$data = fgets($file)` into the "while" statement: `while($data = fgets($file))`

Comment: Thanks [Rylee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10086352/rylee). If I do so, only the first line in the text file will be read. all other entries in the text file will be ignored.

Comment: @[Professor Abronsius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3603681/professor-abronsius): Would you mind to to show me the example? Thanks.

Comment: One way is to use `truncate` to remove EOF and then upload the text file to the web server.